# .htaccess redirects with two elements that need changing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Good morning.

I need to redirect a bunch of URLs from an old site to a new site.  The format of the old URLs is:

http://www.example.com/website-name-blog/post-name.html

I wish to redirect these to:

http://www.example.com/post-name/

So, removing the directory and stripping the .html - the new site already enforces a trailing slash.

I know I can remove the directory easily enough, but is it possible to do this AND strip the .html?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of old site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^.]+)\.html$ /$1/ [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. The old site and new site have the same domain - does this matter?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. Let me know if you have any problem in this rule.

Comment: Hi anubhava, can you just clarify where you mean by the Document Root - is this just the top level directory when I go into the site via an FTP client?

Comment: It is the top level directory where you site's landing index.html or index.php is stored.

Comment: Won't know for sure til site goes live next week. Hopefully I won't be back to bother you, but will set as answer if all goes well :)